# I'm getting a bad requests warning when trying to connect to the API I prepared with Django

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a user API that I have prepared with django. However, when I make API requests with the Postman application for testing purposes, I get a 400 Bad Request warning, what could be the reason? I can write all of my codes as follows if there is any other required code.

**This is views.py code**

```
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
    from rest_framework import status
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    from .serializers import CustomUserSerializer
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
    from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
    
    
    class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
        permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    
        def post(self, request, format='json'):
            serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                user = serializer.save()
                if user:
                    json = serializer.data
                    return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    
    class BlacklistTokenUpdateView(APIView):
        permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        authentication_classes = ()
    
        def post(self, request):
            try:
                refresh_token = request.data["refresh_token"]
                token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
                token.blacklist()
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT)
            except Exception as e:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**This is my urls**

> api/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import CustomUserCreate, BlacklistTokenUpdateView

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', CustomUserCreate.as_view(), name="create_user"),
    path('logout/blacklist/', BlacklistTokenUpdateView.as_view(),
         name='blacklist')
]
```

> core/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("api/post/", include("post.api.urls", namespace="post")),
    path("api/post/audio/", include("post_audio.api.urls", namespace="postaudio")),
    path('api/comment/', include('comment.api.urls', namespace='comment')),
    path("api/categories/", include("post.api.urls", namespace="categories")),
    path("api/author/", include("author.api.urls", namespace="author")),
    path("api/favourites/", include("favourite.api.urls", namespace="favourite")),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> And Also this is my serializers.py code

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import NewUser


class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    user_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ('email', 'user_name', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        # as long as the fields are the same, we can just use this
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to your code
class "CustomUserCreate" retruns 400 error if "serializer.is_valid()" returns false, I think you are not sending required Parametrs inside body of Postman.

in case of class "BlacklistTokenUpdateView" also returns 400 error if any Exception has occurred

Comment: Should i take a look at my serializers code?

Comment: Yes also check body parameters of Postman , these are must match

Comment: ok thank you so much my brother it works :)

Answer (score 2):

A 400 error would likely suggest that the issue lies with something about how you've constructed the requests from that tool.

The email value you are sending is not a valid email format and you also don't appear to be sending a user_name, so I suspect that the requests are failing validation at the serializer level.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/ this is my postman call and here is the result:  {
    "email": [
        "Bu alan zorunlu."
    ],
    "password": [
        "Bu alan zorunlu."
    ]
}

Comment: The email value you are sending is not a valid email format and you also don't appear to be be sending a user_name, so I suspect that the requests are failing validation at the serializer level.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, you can get bad requests from two places: `CustomUserCreate` and `BlacklistTokenUpdateView`.
To help you debugging this you could add logs including `serializer.errors` (in `CustomUserCreate`) and inside the except in `BlacklistTokenUpdateView`. A good practice is avoid catching generic exceptions. This way you'll know exactly why it failed.